# Filtering routes with react-router's `match`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, server-side-rendering

I have a redux application setup with server side rendering via express. I'm interested in "filtering" the routes which are server-rendered, essentially ignoring certain routes. The major reason for this is to ignore routes which require token-authorized API requests to be completed.

server.js

```
import Express from 'express';
import getRoutes from './routes';
import { match, createMemoryHistory } from 'react-router';

app.use((req, res) => {
  const allRoutes = getRoutes(store);
  match({ routes: allRoutes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    ...
  });
});
```

routes.js

```
import { IndexRoute, Route } from 'react-router';
import {
  App,
  HomePage,
  About,
  Contact,
  RestrictedPage
} from 'containers'

export default () => (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
    <Route path='/about' component={About} />
    <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
    <Route path='/restricted/:id' component={RestrictedPage} />
  </Route>
);
```

I essentially just don't want to server-render RestrictedPage. I was hoping maybe I could use something like:

`<Route path='/restricted/:id' component={RestrictedPage} noServerRender={true} />`

and then filter that in `server.js` something like:

`match({ routes: filterRoutes(routes), location: req.url }, ...`

But the parameter that `match` takes seems to only be the full object returned by `getRoutes()`.

Anyway any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.